# Avoiding advertising before watching Youtube/Dailymotion videos

Tags: video, youtube

When playing videos on Dailymotion or Youtube websites, we often need to wait some seconds (advertising) before really watching the video. The same occurs when using Dailymotion or Youtube player (when you play videos on your own websites for example).

Is it the same when using another video player? I mean avoiding using Dailymotion/Youtube player but a custom plugin.

I am searching for a solution where there are no advertisings.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The advertising isn't really dictated by the player or the browser plug-in itself, it's dictated by the container that it gets embedded in for a particular url.

Take for example:

```
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HW4J-RiCZ2Q
```

The `watch` url embeds the advertisements along with resource(s) into the swf container.

```
youtube.com/v/HW4J-RiCZ2Q
youtube.com/embed/HW4J-RiCZ2Q
```

^ The content for urls above are essentially taken out of the container from the `watch` url.

Same thing for Dailymotion.